# Hector_Slam Imu How to set up the tf tree

Tags: slam, imu, navigation, hector-slam, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I'm currently working with hector_slam for creating maps.
I have written a package for my imu which offers me a rotation matrix, so that i can calculate roll, pitch and yaw.

My question is: How should i connect them to the hector_slam tf tree?

Roll, pitch to base_stabilized->base_link
and
Yaw for orientation to base_footprint->base_stabilized?

or can i put them all together to base_stabilized->base_link? Makes it any difference?

Thx for your response

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42710/hector_slam-imu-how-to-set-up-the-tf-tree/) by [Tirgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2060/tirgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The yaw for base_link and base_stabilized should be the same, it's only the roll and pitch angles that differ between both, as also described [in the setup tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot).
You can use the [hector_imu_attitude_to_tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf) node to conveniently publish the base_stabilized->base_link transform using a IMU message. I just added this to the tutorial, too.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-02-02**:
I have mpu6050 and raspberry pi. I have written a code to publish the yaw, pitch and roll from imu. Now, how can I make hector_imu_attitude_to_tf node get this data? I mean, should I change any lines of code or will it directly subscribe to these values?